# The use of commit methods in PreparedStatements

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement

When using Java PreparedStatements, a commit makes any change to the database permanent.  What I'm trying to understand is the implications of this.   In particular, can I read a generated key from an insert statement prior to committing?   Can I follow my insert statement with an update statement using the value I retrieved from the database prior to executing the commit as in the following code snippet?   Or should I have a commit after the first insert statement, and then a second commit after the update statement.

```
String insertString = "insert into charges(acct,servicedate,cdmcode,price,quantity,revenuecode,chargeid,id,mod) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    String updateString = "update charges set chargeid = ? where indx = ?";
    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    insertcharge = connection.prepareStatement(insertString,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    insertcharge.setString(1, newacct);
    insertcharge.setString(2, servicedate);
    insertcharge.setString(3, cdmcode);
    insertcharge.setString(4, price);
    insertcharge.setString(5, quantity);
    insertcharge.setString(6, revenuecode);
    insertcharge.setString(7, "0");
    insertcharge.setString(8, id);
    insertcharge.setString(9, mods);
    insertcharge.executeUpdate();
    ResultSet rs = insertcharge.getGeneratedKeys();
    int thekey = 0;
    if (rs.next()){
        thekey = rs.getInt(1);
    }
    insertcharge = connection.prepareStatement(updateString);
    insertcharge.setInt(1, thekey);
    insertcharge.setInt(2, thekey);
    insertcharge.executeUpdate();
    connection.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to commit to get the generated key. Inside transaction all changes are visible immediately. As for auto-incremented values they never rollback, auto-increment mechanism works outside the scope of transactions.

Answer (score 3):

When you disable auto commit, each of your SQL statements are executed in a transaction which are then committed as one atomic unit when you call `commit`. If any of the statements fail in the commit, then the whole transaction fails and you can roll it all back.

If you want to your code to behave this way, then you should do it all within one transaction.

If you want to have multiple transactions so each block is committed independently of one another, you can do it that way as well.

Whether you use one or multiple transactions can be influenced by your business logic/needs.

Here is an example showing how to roll them back http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html